# Laravel livewire updatedselect cant have join value

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, dropdown, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

Im beginner at livewire and laravel, Im trying to add left join in my updatedSelect function, but when im select option in my web app, the value is become null.

Here's livewire controller

```
public $selectedUser = null;
public $selectedPet = null;
public $pet;
    
public function updatedSelectedUser($user)
{
    $this->pet = Pet::where('user_id', $user)
    ->leftjoin('grooms', 'grooms.pet_id', '=', 'pets.id')
    ->whereNull('grooms.pet_id')
    ->get();
}
```

And here's my view

```
               <div class="mt-4">
                @if(!is_null($pet))
                  <div class="mt-4">
                    <x-jet-label for="pet_id" value="{{ __('Nama Pet') }}" />
                    <select class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" wire:model="selectedPet"> 
                          <option selected>--Nama hewan--</option>
                        @foreach ($pet as $item)
                          <option value= "{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                      {{$pet}}
                    @error('selectedPet') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
                  </div>  
                  @endif
              </div>
```

The problems that i got in this pict
[The value beome null when i selected the option in 'nama hewan" dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78f9q.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updating($user){
$this->pet = Pet::where('user_id', $user)
->leftJoin('grooms', 'grooms.pet_id', '=', 'pets.id')
->whereNull('grooms.pet_id')
->get();
}
```

updating is the function where the update the each event of the input like you have write 'A' input field the updating will update.

Comment: It didnt works on me

Comment: can you show me your code

Comment: i had public repo for this, https://github.com/mochyahyaya/healtcare.git, and thank you for your help

Comment: which controller issue